# Showing UI for android app for the first time and hide it from menu

Tags: android, service

I am developing an android device anti-theft application in which the user's phone would automatically send a sms to the recovery mobile numbers with new numbers' details on boot. I used SmsManager with BroadCastReceiver and everything was good till that. But I want the UI part to be visible when I install the app to get the recovery numbers from the users only for the first time and then hide the app and only send sms'on boot later(after first time,work only on background). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: use shared prefernce

Answer (score 0):

Use [`PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int)) to disable the Activity that has the main launch intent filter after setup is complete.

Answer (score -1):

So many possibilities which you can try out are available

1. Use shared preferences in application. This checks whether our application installed is populated with the values that you want to cross check during boot up time
2. Use SQLITE DB to store values which can be encrypted. Check for the business logic and process accordingly.
3. Update data in your server and every time app is up , cross check with server data and run your logic.
4. File system (creating file and writing/reading data) This is the last and not advisable option

If you want references , how to make all these pls refer the following links

[Android Shared Preference Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)
[Android Sqlite example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)[Android file System example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to launch the Activity exactly once after it has been installed. In that case, when that specific activity is launched you can create a SharedPreference and save a value in there! And next time you launch, check if that value exists, if it doesn't launch the activity, else do the other option. Here is how I did it.

In the Activity to be launched once:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivitySession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
    ed.putString("HASH", hash_received);
    ed.putString("MOB",mob_no);
    ed.apply();
```

And then in Activity before that, I implemented:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivitySession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String abc = pref.getString("HASH","");
            if(abc.equals(Test))
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();

            }
            else
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, FeedActivity.class));
                finish();

            }
```

Hope it helps! Happy coding!